# Input value returning undefined

Tags: jquery, input, text, jquery-events

I am using https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker and wish to fire an ajax call when the date is changed.

First things first determine when the date has been changed by plugging into the - plug into the `changeDate` event. Then alerting the value in the text box to the screen...

http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events.html#changedate

Here is my fiddle....

http://jsfiddle.net/MangoMM/nY5C6/3/

HTML

```
<div class="input-group date">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Select Date" readonly="1" 
        data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" 
        data-date-start-date="today()" data-date-autoclose="true" 
        data-date-days-of-week-disabled="[2,4,6,0]" 
        data-date-today-highlight="1" name="appointment[date]" 
        type="text" id="appointment[date]" /> 
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".input-group.date").on('changeDate', function(){
    alert(event.type + " is fired: " + $('#appointment[date]').val());
});
```

I have tried various combinations including `$(this).val()` and others, but no luck...

Why is my input value showing as undefined? How can I get the value in the text box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `[]` with with two backslashes: \\.

```
alert(event.type + " is fired: " + $('#appointment\\[date\\]').val());
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mPxBK/2/)

From [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\.

Additionally, You need to pass `event` to event handler

*Complete Code*

```
$(".input-group.date").on('changeDate', function(event){
    alert(event.type + " is fired: " + $('#appointment\\[date\\]').val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
console.log($(".form-control").val());
```

`[]` is an attribute selector.

In other words `$('.form-control[data-provide="datepicker"]').val()` would be valid.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use jsf framework?
If so, you can try use Firebug and inspect for looking element ID.

This framework often generate "**form:**" before  real ID.

**You can try**

```
$("#form\\:appointment\\[date\\]").val();
```

Answer (score -1):

First you need to pass event to function and escape the brackers

```
$(".input-group.date").on('changeDate', function(event){
   //                                             ^event
    alert(event.type + " is fired: " + $('#appointment\\[date\\]').val());
    //                                                ^^     ^^ escape brackers
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nY5C6/4/)